# I can not decrease MTU on my nic

Tags: mtu

I'm trying to decrease the MTU value on my machine but I receive this response:

```
[root@apache1bpreprod acn]# ifconfig eth0 mtu 1350
SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument
```

Why? i expect problems to increase not to decrease.
Can you help me? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, A little more information would be helpful here. What Distro are you using? same error with the command under sudo?

Comment: @Stese: I agree that more information is needed. However, he is logged in as the root user so "sudo" won't do much good here.

Comment: Well spotted! Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little google-foo and came up on this post on NIX_craft.
[Nix-Craft link to MTU changes](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-redhat-fedora-debian-linux-mtu-size/)

it seems to suggest you need to add the instruction to bring the NIC up, when setting the MTU.

```
ifconfig eth1 mtu 9000 up
```

I'd wager you need to bring the NIC down first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support.
I tried to set the same value on another Linux machine with the same operating system Red Hat 7.2 and I had not problems.
Yesterday instead I set the same value on three Linux machines with Red Hat 7.3 and I had problem with SSH access for two machines. My worry is if the machine will not restart network interface or can create problem with the SSH access.

I would understand if I can proceed with a command as

ifconfig eth0 mtu 1360

that not require a restart of the interface. On this machine I tried to restart the machine without success.
Thanks a lot for support.